# Missing number, treated as zero when creating a chapter

Tags: sectioning, chapters, sharelatex, abnt

I'm trying to create a chapter, the first subdivision in the document, but whenever I try the `\chapter{...}` command, I get this error:

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.62 \chapter{Test}                   
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

I can create `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection` and even `\part` commands with no problem. The bit of code I'm trying to place the chapter in is:

```
\part{Glossário de siglas}
\chapter{Test}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{GPS}{\textit{General Problem Solver}}
\end{acronym}

\newpage
\section{Introdução}
```

EDIT: Here's a small code where the problem appears

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{abntex2}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Glossário de siglas}

Teste

\end{document}
```

Log-file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.3.24)  18 NOV 2015 10:47
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(/compile/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/abntex2/abntex2.cls
Document Class: abntex2 2015/01/26 v1.9.3 abnTeX2
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2015/03/05 v3.7c configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
\onelineskip=\skip41
\lxvchars=\skip42
\xlvchars=\skip43
\@memcnta=\count79
\c@@memmarkcntra=\count80
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifetex/ifetex.sty
Package: ifetex 2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/plain/ifetex/ifetex.tex)) (/usr/local/t
exlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
\stockheight=\skip44
\stockwidth=\skip45
\trimtop=\skip46
\trimedge=\skip47
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
Package: etex 2015/03/02 v2.1 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
\et@xins=\count81
) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem10.clo
File: mem10.clo 2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
)
\binding=\skip48
\spinemargin=\skip49
\foremargin=\skip50
\uppermargin=\skip51
\lowermargin=\skip52
\headdrop=\skip53
\normalrulethickness=\skip54
\mem@maxheadheight=\skip55
\mem@maxfootheight=\skip56
\headwidth=\skip57
\c@storedpagenumber=\count82
\memPD=\dimen102
\m@mabparskip=\skip58
\thanksmarkwidth=\skip59
\thanksmarksep=\skip60
\droptitle=\skip61
\c@book=\count83
\c@part=\count84
\c@chapter=\count85
\c@section=\count86
\c@subsection=\count87
\c@subsubsection=\count88
\c@paragraph=\count89
\c@subparagraph=\count90
\beforechapskip=\skip62
\midchapskip=\skip63
\afterchapskip=\skip64
\chapindent=\skip65
\bottomsectionskip=\skip66
\secindent=\skip67
\beforesecskip=\skip68
\aftersecskip=\skip69
\subsecindent=\skip70
\beforesubsecskip=\skip71
\aftersubsecskip=\skip72
\subsubsecindent=\skip73
\beforesubsubsecskip=\skip74
\aftersubsubsecskip=\skip75
\paraindent=\skip76
\beforeparaskip=\skip77
\afterparaskip=\skip78
\subparaindent=\skip79
\beforesubparaskip=\skip80
\aftersubparaskip=\skip81
\pfbreakskip=\skip82
\c@@ppsavesec=\count91
\c@@ppsaveapp=\count92
\ragrparindent=\dimen103
\everylistparindent=\dimen104
\parsepi=\skip83
\topsepi=\skip84
\itemsepi=\skip85
\parsepii=\skip86
\topsepii=\skip87
\topsepiii=\skip88
\itemsepii=\skip89
\itemsepiii=\skip90
\partopsepii=\skip91
\partopsepiii=\skip92
\m@msavetopsep=\skip93
\m@msavepartopsep=\skip94
\@enLab=\toks14
\abstitleskip=\skip95
\absleftindent=\skip96
\abs@leftindent=\dimen105
\absrightindent=\skip97
\absparindent=\skip98
\absparsep=\skip99
\c@vslineno=\count93
\c@poemline=\count94
\c@modulo@vs=\count95
\c@memfvsline=\count96
\vleftskip=\skip100
\vrightskip=\skip101
\stanzaskip=\skip102
\versewidth=\skip103
\vgap=\skip104
\vindent=\skip105
\vleftmargin=\dimen106
\c@verse=\count97
\c@chrsinstr=\count98
\beforepoemtitleskip=\skip106
\afterpoemtitleskip=\skip107
\c@poem=\count99
\beforePoemTitleskip=\skip108
\midPoemTitleskip=\skip109
\afterPoemTitleskip=\skip110
\col@sep=\dimen107
\extrarowheight=\dimen108
\NC@list=\toks15
\extratabsurround=\skip111
\backup@length=\skip112
\TX@col@width=\dimen109
\TX@old@table=\dimen110
\TX@old@col=\dimen111
\TX@target=\dimen112
\TX@delta=\dimen113
\TX@cols=\count100
\TX@ftn=\toks16
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen114
\lightrulewidth=\dimen115
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen116
\belowrulesep=\dimen117
\belowbottomsep=\dimen118
\aboverulesep=\dimen119
\abovetopsep=\dimen120
\cmidrulesep=\dimen121
\cmidrulekern=\dimen122
\defaultaddspace=\dimen123
\@cmidla=\count101
\@cmidlb=\count102
\@aboverulesep=\dimen124
\@belowrulesep=\dimen125
\@thisruleclass=\count103
\@lastruleclass=\count104
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen126
\ctableftskip=\skip113
\ctabrightskip=\skip114
\abovecolumnspenalty=\count105
\@linestogo=\count106
\@cellstogo=\count107
\@cellsincolumn=\count108
\crtok=\toks17
\@mincolumnwidth=\dimen127
\c@newflo@tctr=\count109
\mem@margin@floatbox=\box26
\@contcwidth=\skip115
\@contindw=\skip116
\abovecaptionskip=\skip117
\belowcaptionskip=\skip118
\subfloattopskip=\skip119
\subfloatcapskip=\skip120
\subfloatcaptopadj=\skip121
\subfloatbottomskip=\skip122
\subfloatlabelskip=\skip123
\subfloatcapmargin=\dimen128
\c@@contsubnum=\count110
\m@mscap@capbox=\box27
\m@mscap@fbox=\box28
\sidecapsep=\dimen129
\sidecapwidth=\dimen130
\m@m@tempdima=\dimen131
\m@mscapraise=\dimen132
\sidecapraise=\dimen133
\m@mscapmainwidth=\dimen134
\m@mscaplkern=\dimen135
\beforeepigraphskip=\skip124
\afterepigraphskip=\skip125
\epigraphwidth=\skip126
\epigraphrule=\skip127
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 7514.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 7522.
\tocentryskip=\skip128
\tocbaseline=\skip129
\cftparskip=\skip130
\cftbeforebookskip=\skip131
\cftbookindent=\dimen136
\cftbooknumwidth=\dimen137
\cftbeforepartskip=\skip132
\cftpartindent=\skip133
\cftpartnumwidth=\skip134
\cftbeforechapterskip=\skip135
\cftchapterindent=\skip136
\cftchapternumwidth=\skip137
\cftbeforesectionskip=\skip138
\cftsectionindent=\skip139
\cftsectionnumwidth=\skip140
\cftbeforesubsectionskip=\skip141
\cftsubsectionindent=\skip142
\cftsubsectionnumwidth=\skip143
\cftbeforesubsubsectionskip=\skip144
\cftsubsubsectionindent=\skip145
\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth=\skip146
\cftbeforeparagraphskip=\skip147
\cftparagraphindent=\skip148
\cftparagraphnumwidth=\skip149
\cftbeforesubparagraphskip=\skip150
\cftsubparagraphindent=\skip151
\cftsubparagraphnumwidth=\skip152
\prechapterprecisshift=\dimen138
\c@maxsecnumdepth=\count111
\bibindent=\dimen139
\bibitemsep=\skip153
\indexcolsep=\skip154
\indexrule=\skip155
\indexmarkstyle=\toks18
\@indexbox=\insert233
\glossarycolsep=\dimen140
\glossaryrule=\dimen141
\sideparvshift=\skip156
\sideins=\insert232
\sidebartopsep=\skip157
\sidebarhsep=\skip158
\sidebarvsep=\skip159
\sidebarwidth=\skip160
\footmarkwidth=\skip161
\footmarksep=\skip162
\footparindent=\skip163
\footinsdim=\skip164
\footinsv@r=\insert231
\@mpfootinsv@r=\insert230
\m@m@k=\count112
\m@m@h=\dimen142
\m@mipn@skip=\skip165
\sidefootins=\insert229
\sidefootadjust=\skip166
\sidefootheight=\skip167
\sidefoothsep=\skip168
\sidefootvsep=\skip169
\sidefootwidth=\skip170
\m@mdownsf=\skip171
\c@sidefootnote=\count113
\sidefootmarkwidth=\skip172
\sidefootmarksep=\skip173
\sidefootparindent=\skip174
\c@pagenote=\count114
\c@pagenoteshadow=\count115
\mem@pn@lastkern=\skip175
\every@verbatim=\toks19
\afterevery@verbatim=\toks20
\verbatim@line=\toks21
\tab@position=\count116
\verbatim@in@stream=\read1
\verbatimindent=\skip176
\verbatim@out=\write3
\bvboxsep=\skip177
\c@memfbvline=\count117
\c@bvlinectr=\count118
\bvnumlength=\skip178
\fb@frw=\dimen143
\fb@frh=\dimen144
\FrameRule=\dimen145
\FrameSep=\dimen146
\c@cp@cntr=\count119
LaTeX Info: Redefining \: on input line 11980.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \! on input line 11982.
\c@ism@mctr=\count120
\c@xsm@mctr=\count121
\c@csm@mctr=\count122
\c@ksm@mctr=\count123
\c@xksm@mctr=\count124
\c@cksm@mctr=\count125
\c@msm@mctr=\count126
\c@xmsm@mctr=\count127
\c@cmsm@mctr=\count128
\c@bsm@mctr=\count129
\c@workm@mctr=\count130
\c@sheetsequence=\count131
\c@lastsheet=\count132
\c@lastpage=\count133
\c@figure=\count134
\c@lofdepth=\count135
\cftbeforefigureskip=\skip179
\cftfigureindent=\skip180
\cftfigurenumwidth=\skip181
\c@table=\count136
\c@lotdepth=\count137
\cftbeforetableskip=\skip182
\cfttableindent=\skip183
\cfttablenumwidth=\skip184
Package abstract [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package appendix [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package array [2008/09/09] emulated by memoir.
Package booktabs [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package ccaption [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package changepage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngcntr [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package crop emulated by memoir.
Package dcolumn [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package delarray [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package enumerate [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package epigraph [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package ifmtarg [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package index [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package makeidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package moreverb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package mparhack [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package needspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package newfile [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package nextpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package pagenote [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package parskip [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package patchcmd [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package setspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package shortvrb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package showidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tabularx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titleref [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titling [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocbibind [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocloft [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocvsec2 [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verbatim [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verse [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mempatch.sty
Package: mempatch 2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \MakeTextUppercase on input line 47.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \MakeTextLowercase on input line 50.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
Package: hobsub-generic 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifluatex' (already loaded).
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifpdf' (already loaded).
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2011/01/30 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks22
) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen147
\Hy@linkcounter=\count138
\Hy@pagecounter=\count139
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count140
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4443.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4448.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4451.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4458.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4463.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4688.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count141
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5041.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen148
\Fld@menulength=\count142
\Field@Width=\dimen149
\Fld@charsize=\dimen150
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6295.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6300.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6303.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6310.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6315.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6320.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6325.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6365.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6369.
\Hy@abspage=\count143
\c@Item=\count144
\c@Hfootnote=\count145
) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memhfixc.sty
Package: memhfixc 2013/05/30 v1.17 nameref/hyperref package fixes for memoir cl
ass
\c@memhycontfloat=\count146
\c@Hpagenote=\count147
)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count148
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count149
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip185
) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/bookmark.sty
Package: bookmark 2011/12/02 v1.24 PDF bookmarks (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/bkm-pdftex.def
File: bkm-pdftex.def 2011/12/02 v1.24 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
\BKM@id=\count150
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-portuges/portuges.ldf
Language: portuges 2008/03/18 v1.2q Portuguese support from the babel system
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2014/09/25 3.9l Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count151
\U@D=\dimen151
)
\l@brazil = a dialect from \language\l@portuges 
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 145.
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty
Package: enumitem 2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
\labelindent=\skip186
\enit@outerparindent=\dimen152
\enit@toks=\toks23
\enit@inbox=\box29
\enitdp@description=\count152
)

******************************************************
Stock height and width: 845.04684pt by 597.50787pt
Top and edge trims: 0pt and 0pt
Page height and width: 845.04684pt by 597.50787pt
Text height and width: 706pt by 455pt
Spine and edge margins: 85.35826pt and 56.9055pt
Upper and lower margins: 85.35826pt and 53.68858pt
Headheight and headsep: 12pt and 18.06749pt
Footskip: 25.29494pt
Columnsep and columnseprule: 10pt and 0pt
Marginparsep and marginparwidth: 7pt and 42.9055pt
Sidecapsep and sidecapwidth: 7pt and 117pt
Sidebarhsep and sidebarwidth: 7pt and 117pt
Sidebarvsep and sidebartopsep: 12pt and 0pt
Sidebarheight: 596.39996pt
Sidefoothsep and sidefootwidth: 7pt and 117pt
Sidefootvsep and sidefootheight: 12pt and 596.39996pt
******************************************************

\c@abntex@bookmarkcounter=\count153
\cftlastnumwidth=\skip187
\chapternamenumlength=\skip188
\ABNTEXcitacaorecuo=\skip189
\c@alineasi=\count154
\c@alineasii=\count155
\enitdp@alineas=\count156
\c@subalineasi=\count157
\enitdp@subalineas=\count158
\c@incisosi=\count159
\enitdp@incisos=\count160
\ABNTEXsignwidth=\skip190
\ABNTEXsignthickness=\skip191
\ABNTEXsignskip=\skip192
) (/compile/output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box30
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 3.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count161
)
Redoing nameref's sectioning
Redoing nameref's label
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 3.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 3.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 3.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 3.
\myptabbox=\box31
\myptabboxwidth=\skip193
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.5 \chapter{Glossário de siglas}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.5 \chapter{Glossário de siglas}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

Missing character: There is no � in font cmss17!
Missing character: There is no � in font cmss17!
[1


{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 9.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 9.
(/compile/output.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 9.

 *File List*
 abntex2.cls    2015/01/26 v1.9.3 abnTeX2
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  memoir.cls    2015/03/05 v3.7c configurable book, report, article document cl
ass
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifetex.sty    2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
    etex.sty    2015/03/02 v2.1 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
   mem10.clo    2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
mempatch.sty    2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
memhfixc.sty    2013/05/30 v1.17 nameref/hyperref package fixes for memoir clas
s
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
bookmark.sty    2011/12/02 v1.24 PDF bookmarks (HO)
bkm-pdftex.def    2011/12/02 v1.24 bookmark driver for pdfTeX (HO)
   babel.sty    2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package
portuges.ldf    2008/03/18 v1.2q Portuguese support from the babel system
enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
 ***********

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 9.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 9.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 8873 strings out of 493109
 129502 string characters out of 6135010
 245553 words of memory out of 5000000
 12313 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4849 words of font info for 18 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 39i,9n,25p,223b,338s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss17.pfb>
Output written on /compile/output.pdf (1 page, 19755 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 26 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 20 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 3 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 9 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: @Mariana: `abntex2` was updated in April 2015 -- perhaps you have some older version?

Comment: Could be! I'll try to compile it by hand (out of sharelatex)

Comment: I just tried texlive 2014 and still no error. @Mariana you could add `\listfiles` to your document and post the full log from your small example file, so we see exactly where the error occurs, and what file versions you have

Comment: Yeah there doesn't seem to be a problem when compiling by hand. It's definitely something with Sharelatex. should I delete the question?

Comment: probably, although you might want to report it to sharelatex (I assume that's possible) Glad you got something working, if not on the site you wanted.

Comment: @Mariana: I strongly suggest to work with compilation by hand! I use LaTeX only this way, without online editors or TeXMaker etc. stuff!

Comment: @Mariana Did you report it already? If not, i can ping them to take a look.

Comment: @Johannes_B I suspect it's an etex.sty thing (my tl14 is updated more than that log) can you add `\RequirePackage{etex}` as first line in sharelatex?

Comment: @David Oh: `(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
Package: etex 2015/03/02 v2.1 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
\et@xins=\count79
)` THe package is loaded by `abntex` as seen in the filelist above, i didn't spot that one before.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes that's why I asked, that's an older version and loaded late

Answer (score 5):

I get the error with tl14 and it goes away if I add the calc package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{abntex2}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Glossário de siglas}

Teste

\end{document}
```

But I have no idea if this a workaround which only hides some other problem, or the real solution.

Comment: I think you spotted the correct cause. When you mentioned `calc`, I remembered some detective work from egreg when looking at another `abntex2` issue: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21242731#21242731